# ImageMagick - How to avoid overwriting existing files with mogrify?

Tags: macos, bash, imagemagick, mogrify

I have these files under `./`:

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
256/a.jpg
```

I'm running this command to convert files to 256px:

```sh
mogrify -path ./256/ -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

But this command always overrides the existing files in `256`, such as `256/a.jpg`. Even though the images look the same, `git diff` still detects changes in the file. How can I avoid overwriting existing files with `mogrify`?

Versions:

```
ImageMagick 7.0.10-23 Q16 x86_64 2020-07-05
64bit Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73
```

---

Edit:

My desired result is:

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
256/a.jpg (Unchanged)
256/b.jpg (Created)
```

[@Sam Forbis' Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1575008/1018325)
Using `convert -resize 256x256 *.jpg -append ./256/*.jpg` would result in:

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
256/a.jpg (Unchanged)
255/a-0.jpg (Created)
256/a-1.jpg (Created)
```

Comment: The `-write` option does what you want.
`for f in *; do mogrify -quality 0.75 -resize 1024x1024 -write out-$f $f; done`

Answer (score 5):

You should use the command `convert` instead of `mogrify`. From the [man page for `mogrify`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mogrify):

> Mogrify overwrites the original image file, whereas, convert writes to a different image file.

Looks like the input options are identical for `convert`. You just need to specify output options and an output file name as specified by the [man page for `convert`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/convert):

```
convert [input-options] input-file [output-options] output-file
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! But a member in the forum said that [*You cannot use wildcards for both input and output with magick/convert. To process a folder of images, you need to use magick mogrify*](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33140). And I've edited my question to include the results of using `convert`.

Comment: @Hykilpikonna after reading your edits to your question, it looks like what you're trying to do cannot be accomplished with mogrify and/or convert alone. You will need to write a bash or batch script to assist you in your task.